# How to update the client's object properties in <div>?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a dashboard web app (ASP MVC Net Core 3.1), like the common dashboard app, some info will be processed at the backend and will update the dashboard periodically.

**example:**
Monitoring CPU usage %

```
<div class="text-uppercase mb-1"><small><b>CPU Usage</b></small></div>
     <div class="progress progress-xs">
          <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
          </div><small class="text-muted">Current Process % ${cpuUsage}.</small>
```

we use WebSocket to communicate with the clients, so if for example, the client receives a string 'UPDATE_CPU_USAGE;30' then the dashboard value should be updated to 30 (in this case aria-valuenow must be updated to 30). Currently the client already able to receive the strings from websocket, but I don't have an idea on how to update the client's object properties in

**updated**

the websocket listener is on the main page, how to update the `'<div>'` and  the aria-valuenow of the other page in that located in javascript?

need an idea.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set an Id to your progressbar

```
          <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
```

using javascript, once the value is received, you can do

```
var progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
    if (progressBar != undefined) {
        progressBar.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', 30); // replace your value instead of 30
    }
```

Comment: sorry, I have updated my question, but the websocket listener is on the main page (different with dashboard page)